Why is the product of $n$ round-off errors bounded by $\frac{nu}{1 - nu}$?
I am having some trouble with proving the following inequality (arising from numerical analysis).
If $\rho = \pm 1$ and $|\delta_i| \leq u$, and $nu < 1$, then
$$\prod_{i = 1}^n (1 + \delta_i)^{\rho_i} = 1 + \theta_n$$ with $$|\theta_n| \leq \frac{nu}{1 - nu}$$.
If all $\rho_i = 1$, then we get the following.
$$\prod_{i = 1}^n (1 + \delta_i) = 1 + \theta_n.$$
Now
$$|\theta_n|= \left|\prod_{i = 1}^n (1 + \delta_i) - 1 \right| \leq (1 + u)^n  - 1.$$
Using $1 + x \leq e^x$ for $x \geq 0$ and the Taylor series of $e^x$, we get
$$|\theta_n| \leq (e^{u})^n - 1 = e^{nu} - 1 = nu + \frac{(nu)^2}{2!} + \cdots <$$
$$nu\left(1 + \left(\frac{nu}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{nu}{2}\right)^2 + \cdots ...\right) = nu \cdot \frac{1}{1 - nu/2}.$$
which is actually slightly tighter. I suppose we can split the product up in positive and negative $\rho_i$, and use the reverse triangle inequality to get
$$\left|\prod_{i = 1}^n\frac{1}{(1 + \delta_i)} - 1\right| \leq \frac{1}{(1 - u)^n} - 1.$$
The same technique does not really work here because an upper bound $e^{n(1 - u)}$ is not tight enough.

$$0\leq|\delta_i|\leq u<\frac1n\leq1$$
$$|\theta|=\left|\frac{(1+\delta_1)(1+\delta_2)\cdots(1+\delta_p)}{(1+\delta_{p+1})(1+\delta_{p+2})\cdots(1+\delta_{p+q})}-1\right|$$
$$\overset!\leq\frac{(1+u)(1+u)\cdots(1+u)}{(1-u)(1-u)\cdots(1-u)}-1$$
$$=\frac{(1+u)^p}{(1-u)^q}-1$$
$$\leq\frac1{(1-u)^p(1-u)^q}-1$$
$$=\frac1{(1-u)^n}-1$$
$$\overset*\leq\frac1{1-nu}-1$$
$$=\frac{nu}{1-nu}$$
$(!)$ follows from the power series expansions of both sides, using $1/(1-x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ for $x=-\delta_i$ and for $x=u$. (Fully expand the products, so that the $1$ cancels.)
$(*)$ is Bernoulli's inequality.
